# Change arrow style of firefox default number input

Tags: css, firefox

Since I've updated to the latest version of Firefox (57) here's how the `<input type="number">` render:

[image]

Which is quite user unfriendly. Is there a way to override the up/down arrow rendering via css or do I have to use a custom plugin?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Kpx5K2c.png — I can't reproduce the problem. This looks like a bug in the interaction between Firefox and something on your system (e.g. GTK and your choice of theme).

Comment: Like something in W10? @Quentin